# api token from ansible vault that is encrypted does not work with my playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to pull an api token that is encrypted from an ansible vault and use it in a lookup that https://docs.w3cub.com/ansible/collections/community/general/tss_lookup.html has in their example.  For some reason I can hardcode the token value and it works, but trying to use the one from the vault fails.  I can see via  debug msg that the token value it pulls from the vault matches what I use when I hard code it.  I am not sure what is up.

The code snippet:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      secret_password: >-
        {{
            ((lookup(
                'community.general.tss',
                123456,
                base_url='https://our.thycoticserver.com/secretserver/',
                token={{ my_token }}
            )  | from_json).get('items') | items2dict(key_name='slug', value_name='itemValue'))['password']
        }}
  tasks:
      - ansible.builtin.debug:
          msg: the password is {{ secret_password }}
      - ansible.builtin.debug:
          msg: the token is {{ my_token }}
```

The lookup fails to connect to our password manager if I try and use the {{ my_token }} for the token value.  It does display properly in the message: the token is ...

I tried putting {{ my_token }} in double quotes and single quotes and it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Do not nest moustaches. Once you are in a Jinja context, you do not need (and should not use) additional Jinja delimiters for sub-expressions.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      secret_password: >-
        {{
            ((lookup(
                'community.general.tss',
                123456,
                base_url='https://our.thycoticserver.com/secretserver/',
                token=my_token
            ) | from_json)['items'] | items2dict(key_name='slug', value_name='itemValue'))['password']
        }}
  tasks:
      - ansible.builtin.debug:
          msg: the password is {{ secret_password }}
      - ansible.builtin.debug:
          msg: the token is {{ my_token }}
```

Comment: ah, that works.  How do you use quotes on this?  with "my_token" eval the value in the double quotes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Inside a Jinja expression you should not quote variable names, since that turns them into strings; `token=my_token` uses the value of `my_token`, `token='my_token'` uses the literal string "my_token". Quotes outside of the expression are irrelevant from a templating perspective, they're just used to make the YAML parser happy: `msg: '{{ my_token }}'` needs to be quoted because it starts with `{`, `msg: the token is {{ my_token }}` does not because it starts with `t`.

Comment: just old concern that token has special characters in it like * or $ or whatever and single quotes are used sometimes to address that.

Comment: This is one of the reasons you should not nest moustaches; when you do things correctly you do not need to worry about how Jinja will intepret the contents of the variable. With `{{ foo={{ my_token }} }}` things will break because the context that this is a string value is lost, so you need to try to quote it to turn it back into a string from the outer expression's perspective: `{{ foo='{{ my_token }}' }}`. With `{{ foo=my_token }}` there's no loss of context, and Jinja passes the value to the lookup intact.